# Sesión en expressjs no se mantiene al redirigir

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, session, express-session

Al hacer login un usuario y almacenar los datos con éxito mediante `express-session` hago un redirect a la página principal (`res.redirect(url);`). El problema es que al hacer dicho redirect, los datos almacenados en las variables de sesión no se mantienen pero, sorprendentemente, si lo hago manualmente (desde el navegador), los datos de la sesión sí que están disponibles. Por ello deduzco que el problema estará en `res.redirect()`, cual es el comportamiento exacto de esta función? Como se podría solucionar este error?

EDIT: Adjunto un ejemplo de la estructura que uso para gestionar las sesiones:

main.js:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var mySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);

let sessionConfiguration = session({
  secret: "SuperSecreto",
  store: sessionStore, //Correctamente configurado
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: false
});

function checkSession(req, res, next) {
  if(req.session.user) {
    console.log("EXISTE ");
    console.log(req.session.test);
    next();
  } else {
    console.log("NO EXISTE ");
    next();
  }
}

//En el middleware checkSession con el uso de res.redirect siempre
//aparece NO EXISTE
app.use('/', sessionConfiguration, checkSession, router);
```

redirect.js:

```
router.get('/ruta', function (req, res) {  

     req.session.test = "hola"
     console.log(req.session.test);

      //LOS DATOS DE LA SESION SE PIERDEN AL HACER EL REDIRECT
      res.redirect("/");

  });
```

EDIT:

La cookie que se crea cuando no manda correctamente los datos:

```
{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":3600000, "expires":"2019-05-07T21:15:06.727Z", "httpOnly":false, "path":"/", "sameSite":true}}
```

Comment: Deberías añadir el código que genera el error, para que podamos reproducir el problema

Comment: @PabloLozano Cierto! Ya está actualizado

Comment: Se me ocurre un motivo, pero no coincide al 100% con lo expuesto en la pregunta. ¿Es ese código una simplificación del escenario? ¿Estás accediendo a alguna base de datos u otro recurso antes de hacer el redirect?

Comment: Si, ahí están los require que estoy usando. Probé a hacer lo de `app.use(sessionConfiguration)` pero no tuvo resultado tampoco, y a la hora de almacenarse la sesión en el servidor lo hace correctamente. Por ello es posible que pueda cambiar a otra ruta del servidor manualmente y me detecte la sesión. El problema está en que no lo detecta al hacer la redireccion automáticamente con `res.redirect()` @Marcos

Comment: al hacer el redirect y no agregas la cabecera es como si estuvieces en otra session , deberias de crear el header y reenviarlo

Comment: @JackNavaRow Si puede poner un ejemplo a modo de respuesta se lo agradecería muchisimo ^^

Comment: Para mi sigue faltando código para saber qué está pasando, al simplificarlo creo que faltan elementos clave para perder la sesión

Comment: No hay nada más, eso es todo lo que se encarga de la sesión @PabloLozano

Comment: Dos consultas: ¿que tienes en sessionConfiguration? y cuando hace redirect, puedes darle inspeccionar petición y ver las cookie que le envía el navegador en el request tanto en la página normal como la redireccionada.

Comment: Actualizada la pregunta con la cookie y la sessionConfiguration @Ali

Comment: ¿probaste con el método **save**?..... `req.session.save(function(err) {res.redirect('/')})`. Cuando la sesión se guarda correctamente (siempre y cuando `err` no haya si definida), se hace la redirección..... puede que haya algo mal en este código, me base en la documentación.

Comment: @DamiánAlva Si, lo probé tambien... Pero nada, sigue igual :S

Comment: No se si desea usar alguna alternativa para el manejo de las sesiones, por ejemplo los token para las sesiones, a mi forma de ver son faciles de usar y la sesion expira en el momento que el token expire.

Answer (score 3):

Estas haciendo un redirect sin mantener el header,debes agregarlo , tu codigo quedaria algo como :

```
    router.get('/ruta', function (req, res) {  
         req.session.user ="chispas"
         req.session.test = "hola"
         req.session.save(function(err) {
             // session saved
              res.redirect('/')
        })
  });
```

Comment: A la hora de hacer las peticiones (ya sea manualmente con el navegador o automaticamente con `res.redirect()` el header Authorization no aparece por ningun lado :/  Aun asi lo he probado y nada, sigue sin funcionar :/

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar :(

Comment: prueba de nuevo a ver

Comment: Sigue igual, con `res.redirect()` no se guardan los datos

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo puedes solucionar utilizando cookiesSession

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1);
app.use(cookieSession({
                    name: 'session'
                    , secret: randomstring.generate()
                    , httpOnly: true
                    , maxAge: 30 * 60 * 1000
                    , secure: false
                    , overwrite: false
              }));


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/session', session);
```

puedes hacer la prueba asi:

```
router.get('/ruta1', function (req, res) {  

     req.session.test = "hola"


  });
router.get('/ruta2', function (req, res) {  

     console.log(req.session.test);


  });
```

Comment: Cual es la diferencia entre ambos?

Comment: @alex55132 no entiendo tu pregunta, con "ambos " a que te refieres

Comment: Agradezco la respuesta pero me gustaría usar express-session al ser éste mas seguro a la hora de gestionar las sesiones segun las [docs](https://expressjs.com/es/advanced/best-practice-security.html) de expressjs. La solución que me ha dado funciona pero no es la que necesito :(

Comment: @alex55132 como alternativa dejare mi respuesta para que le sirva a alguien

Answer (score 2):

Creo que guardarlo en la sesión puede ser la solución:

```
app.get('/ejemplo', function(req, res) {
  req.session.valid = true;
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

El asunto aquí es que eso no basta, ya que después de la redirección tienes que recuperar el valor:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var passedVariable = req.session.valid;
  req.session.valid = null; // resetea la variable de sesion
  // hacer algo
  console.log("passedVariable="+passedVariable);
});
```

Comment: Qué sentido tiene hacer eso? Estás reseteando la variable de la sesión pero la vas a necesitar igualmente. Además si quisieras modificarla serían lineas extra. No le acabo de ver la lógica a ello :/